# Constructing a list from another list in python

Tags: python, list

I need to write a function of `all_gt(nums, n)` which *nums* is a list of number, *n* is a number, returns the list of numbers from *nums* that are greater than *n*. The order of elements should be preserved.

What I need to do is write in `.append` format and start by initializing the result to an empty list.

For example:

```
all_gt([1,2,3,4],4) => [] 
all_gt([2,3,4,5], 3) => [4,5]
```

This is what I have:

```
def all_gt(nums, n):
    for i in nums:
        if i > n:
            return nums.append(i)
```

I know what I did is wrong and I hope someone can help me solve this question.

Comment: You are on the right track. First, create a new list in the method. Then append all the numbers `i` that are greater than `n` to that new list. After the for loop ran, return the new list.

Comment: There are 3 or 4 issues here. First, `append` returns `None` and modifies `nums`. Second, you need to construct a new list and this is absent from your code. Third, you need to return once *all* the required elements are added to the list, in your code you will return after *one* element is added to your list. Fourth you should look at idiomatic ways of iterating over lists in Python using list comprehensions, even if your assignment requires you to use `append`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your mistake

`return nums.append(i)` appends a value to the list in-place and returns `None`. A workaround can be

```
def all_gt(nums, n):
    num2 = []
    for i in nums:
        if i > n:
            num2.append(i)
    return num2
```

### Better Ways

You can use a list comprehension

```
def all_gt(nums, n):
    return [i for i in nums if i > n]
```

Comment: The return num2 return nothing.

Comment: @icefish I have tested it. It works in my case. Just check if you have missed any part of my answer. Especially `num2 = []` statement after the function definition

Comment: Oh my mistake, I still put a return infront of num2.append(i). It works now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` to keep only the elements greater than `n`:

```
>>> def all_gt(nums, n):
...     return filter(lambda x: x > n, nums)
>>> all_gt([1, 2, 3, 4], 4)
[]
>>> all_gt([2, 3, 4, 5], 3)
[4, 5]
```

Comment: I love the use of functional programming part of python :) ,

Comment: Everyone secretly loves it and hates it

Comment: Yes I know but my assignment needs me to do in .append :(

Comment: Then Rao's answer should do

Answer (score 0):

just applying list comprehension with a if condition will do the trick

```
nums = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
constraint = 3

filtered_result = [ x for x in nums if x > constraint]
```

will result into `[4,5]`